# Issue with Md-select

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, angular-material

I am using the [md-selec](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect)t in angular to select category name. However when I populate category i want to set _Id of mongdb collection to another variable, can I do that ?

collection from mongoDB:

```
categories {
 "name": "Test",
 "_id": "uytsdf66fsfsdf234324234"
}
```

AngularJS:

```
  <md-input-container flex>
        <md-select ng-model="vm.categories" multiple>
           <md-option ng-repeat="category in vm.categorires" value="{{category}}">
      {{category.name}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: What is `md-select`? Do you use an external library or directives?

Comment: Yes it is with angular material

Comment: Added link to the used component